# How to make certain macros defined in document class inaccessible from within an input file using it?

Tags: documentclass-writing

In C#, we can specify certain properties of a class to be private, read only, etc. I want to apply this methodology in writing LaTeX document class if it is possible.

I can find articles pertaining to it neither on the internet nor in a book.

The following is my simplified document class.

```
\ProvidesClass{pst-xport}[a cute document class for my own purpose.]
% .... others ....

\RequirePackage{pstricks}

\newcommand\Left{-1}
\newcommand\Right{1}

\newlength\LeftPadding\setlength{\LeftPadding}{1cm}
\newlength\RightPadding\setlength{\RightPadding}{1cm}

% it must be private
\newlength\PictureWidth

\AtBeginDocument
{
    \setlength{\PictureWidth}{\dimexpr\Right\psxunit-\Left\psxunit\relax}
    \paperwidth=\dimexpr\PictureWidth+\RightPadding+\LeftPadding\relax
    % .... others ....
}


% .... others ....

% it must be private
\parindent=0pt

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% INTERFACES %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\SetPicture[2]
{
    \renewcommand\Left{#1}
    \renewcommand\Right{#3}
}


\newcommand\SetPadding[2]
{
    \setlength{\LeftPadding}{#1}
    \setlength{\RightPadding}{#3}
}

\newcommand\GetPaperWidth{\PictureWidth}
\endinput
```

We use this document class as follows.

```
\documentclass{pst-xport}

\SetPicture{-2}{2}
\SetPadding{0.5cm}{0.5cm}

% \parindent must not be accessible in this input file.
\parindent=10pt

% \PictureWidth must not be accessible in this input file.
\setlength{\PictureWidth}{10cm}

\begin{document}
\parbox{\GetPictureWidth}
{
    I can find a tool to convert
    PDF to EPS in my neither
    bathroom nor kitchen.
}
\end{document}
```

### Questions

If it is possible, how to make certain macros defined in a document class inaccessible from outside?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make truly private methods per se, but you are aware of the way @ works, right?  It is override-able but is standardly used to make macros unavailable in normal documents.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't make macros totally inaccessible from "outside". Even the TeX primitives are not protected and can be redefined (their names, not their function). You can only give your macros a very special name to avoid accidental and hinder deliberate changes on them.

Usually internal macros which are not supposed to be changed by other code include an `@` which is normally not allowed as part of a macro name. This can be changed using `\makeatletter` and changed back to normal with `\makeatother`. Also such internal macros of one package should start with an specific prefix which is normally build from the package name.
So instead of naming an internal macro `\foobar` call it `\xport@foobar`. This won't protect it from some users which really want to change it, but they can consider themselves warned.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you might want to explore `expl3` (part of LaTeX3), which has its own naming conventions (quite distinct from plain TeX's and LaTeX2's `@`).